# Bulma horizontal navbar-menu on tablet breakpoint

Tags: bulma

Is there a way to set the navbar-menu in Bulma to behave on tablet breakpoint the same way it behaves from desktop breakpoint?

I'm looking for the following:
1) Display navbar-menu until the mobile breakpoint is reached.
2) Do not stack the navbar-menu items until the mobile breakpoint is reached.

I can't find a way to do it without manually overriding styles it should be possible to do without overriding styles, but I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is not presently a way to simply set the menu to show on tablets as well as desktops, but [adding a `$navbar-breakpoint` variable is a pretty popular request](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1042).  (A number of workarounds in that issue also.)

Edit: Ah, so i submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/pull/2109) to address this, which means one of the workarounds would be to use [my fork of Bulma which incorporates this fix (and nothing else)](https://github.com/agaric/bulma).

UPDATE!  This was accepted and is in Bulma v0.7.2